# Adding to Numpy Array by-index, where there are duplicate index values

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Imagine we have an array called count, size N, initialized to zero:

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
count = np.zeros(N)  # Shape (N,)
```

And a set of indexes, which may contain duplicates, and a set of boolean values (or whatever kind of values really):

```
IDX = np.random.choice(N,N,replace=True)  # Shape (N,)
mask = np.random.rand(N)>.5  # Shape (N,)
```

I want to count, by location, the number of True's.

```
count[IDX] += mask
```

But for this output, the maximum of count will be equal to 1.

This is because, I assume, duplicates can't be processed in the pipeline like this, either the first or last is used I suspect.

Is there any vectorized equivalent code which can perform this function accurately?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I want to count, by location, the number of True's." What do you mean by "by location"?

Comment: Could you try `np.add.at(count, IDX, mask)`? I think that's what you want.

Comment: Look at `np.add.at`, which is an unbuffered version of `+=`.

Comment: @JMA I understand it's confusing, but I hope the code explains what I mean better. Assuming lets say my IDX variable is [1,3,1,3] and my mask is [True, True, True, False], I want a count of [0,2,0,1] (assuming N == 4).

Comment: @PaulPanzer That sounds right, thanks! I never remember the .at ufunc. I'll try it out

Comment: Yah, that actually solved it, you're a life saver, thanks! How do I, like, upvote you or something? @PaulPanzer

Comment: @Ryan Don't worry, this one's one the house.

Comment: Just remembered: `np.bincount(IDX, mask, minlength=N)` also works and may be a bit faster.

Comment: Two ways to do anything I guess.